# What is difference between bun install and bun add as mentioned in the bun official site? why bun add needed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, package.json, bun

Running `bun install` will install dependencies mentioned in `package.json` file. At least package name needs to be included to `bun add`. But both adds a package to our project right, then why bun add needed? We can achieve the same things with bun install also right. Please clarify me

Comment: what/who are you quoting in your question? `bun add` installs a dependency, and adds the it to `package.json` dependency list ... `bun install` installs dependencies shown in `package.json` dependency list... it's actually quite clearly documented

Comment: _"why bun add needed?"_, for the reason it says. Packages are added with that command. `bun install` won't add packages.

Comment: For example we don't have lodash currently in package.json. then bun install lodash is doing what? isn't it adding/installing lodash newly to package.json?

Comment: @PremchandK — [Not according to the documentation](https://bun.sh/docs/cli/install).

Comment: I've already gone through the docs. And I tested running 
"bun install moment-timezone",
"bun uninstall moment-timezone",
"bun add moment-timezone"
"bun remove moment-timezone"

In all above cases that package has been added/removed to and from the package.json
I still don't know what is the difference between bun install and bun add properly. Instead you guys just down voting my question without proper explanation or answers I think. @JaromandaX

Comment: perhaps `bun` has some undocumented feature where if you use `install` instead of `add` it makes `install` behave like `add` since install is **documented** without any additional arguments (ignoring "options" like `--dry-run` etc), and add is documented as requiring at least one

Comment: Agreed. But every option mentioned in the documentation is also working with `bun i`

Comment: @PremchandK - although it doesn't seem to be documented (haven't looked extensively) ... it does appear that `bun install packagename` works the same as `bun add packagename` (same as `npm`) - however, `bun add` is the *correct* way to do it

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, The key difference between`bun install` and `bun add` is that running `bun install` without a package name checks package.json and install all packages automatically and with `bun add`, it cannot automatically check and install all dependencies in package.json. And at least need to be added package name is required to run `bun add`.

And what we do with `bun add` can be done with `bun install` as well. It is just a personal preference whether to use `bun i` or `bun add`.

Answer (score 0):

While both commands can manage packages, `bun add` is convenient because it not only installs the package but also updates `package.json`. My preference is to simply use `bun i`, which combines both actions, making it easy to add and track dependencies.